# I want my application to identify iPhone models because I'm not using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone

I wrote the code in the following way

```
#define isiPhone6 ( [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667)?TRUE:FALSE
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;


printf("\nDetected Resolution : %d x %d\n\n",(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.width,(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height);


if (isiPhone5)
{
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIphone5" bundle:nil];;
    // this is iphone 4 inch
}

else  if (isiPhone6)
{
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIphone6" bundle:nil];;
    // this is iphone 4 inch
}

else
{
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //Iphone  3.5 inch
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the loop for **iPhone6** is not working and loops working for 3.5 and 4inch. Here loop for is jumping to the iPhone5, iPhone4 but not 6.

Answer (score 0):

See this Class

https://github.com/froztbytes/UIDeviceHardware

Or Create this class

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface UIDeviceHardware : NSObject
     + (NSString *) platform;
     + (NSString *) platformString;
 @end



    #import "UIDeviceHardware.h"
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/sysctl.h>

    @implementation UIDeviceHardware

    + (NSString *) platform{
        size_t size;
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
        char *machine = malloc(size);
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
        NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
        free(machine);
        return platform;
    }

    + (NSString *) platformString{
        NSString *platform = [self platform];
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (CDMA)";

        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (CDMA)";

        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";


        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

        return platform;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: i Just want to know why loop for elseif is jumping(running with ios6 simulator) to other. please let me know i will be thankful for that